# Viewpager Image swipe gallery in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to the android..

I followed this [tutorial](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/) to know how to implement viewpager as image slide gallery swipe gallery. Now, I would like to implement the same image swipe in `fragment` too. I don't know how to proceed. Since it follows Fragment, there is one another function called `onCreateView`. Don't know how to proceed next!

MainActivity.java (Implemented Navigation Drawer with 2 Items in list view)

```
package com.example.sidemenutabstutorial;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
String[] title;
String[] subtitle;
int[] icon;
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();

Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

    // Generate title
    title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2"};

    // Generate subtitle
    subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2"};

    // Generate icon
    icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings};

    // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // Pass results to MenuListAdapter Class
    mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(this, title, subtitle, icon);

    // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

    // Capture button clicks on side menu
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft =

     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

}

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {

ViewPager mViewPager;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    return rootView;
}
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.one,
    R.drawable.two,
    R.drawable.three
   };
ImageAdapter(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
public ImageAdapter(Fragment1 fragment1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return GalImages.length;
}
 
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view == ((ImageView) object);
}
 
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
}
 
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

In Logcat :

```
    10-24 17:15:24.545: D/AndroidRuntime(791): Shutting down VM
10-24 17:15:24.555: W/dalvikvm(791): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:318)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3236)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:105)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.example.sidemenutabstutorial.Fragment1$ImageAdapter.instantiateItem(Fragment1.java:113)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:639)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-24 17:15:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

Pls help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide a sample of the code you already have in your question?  That would help a lot.

Comment: @Derek : I've updated my question sir with full of code. Pls take a look and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) example from documentation, it is a greate start and seems to be what you want.

Comment: sir, my problem is to implement viewpager in fragment. I couldn't able to get in that link *sad*